# What does a "pairing" in the context of vector spaces?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

The statement of an exercise begins by saying:

> Suppose that $\beta:V\otimes V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a non-degenerated symmetric pairing.

where $V$ is vector space finite dimensional.

**My interest is knowing that it is a "pairing"**. My first thought is that this was a bilinear form, but I think it is not correct because the bilinear forms are defined in $V\times V$ not on $V\otimes V$.

I ask for your help with the definition of a 'pairing' as far as possible. Please, provide the names of  some  books where they use this term.

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IB/LinearAlgebra/2008-2009/bilinear-08.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pairing is the same thing as a bilinear map (usually with codomain the base field).

As for the notation, there's a natural equivalence between bilinear maps $A \times B \to C$ and linear maps $A \otimes B \to C$ (this is the point of the tensor product), so they often get conflated.

Comment: What is the meaning of a 'pairing' non-degenerate?

Comment: @DiegoFonseca It means that if for some $v$ we have $\beta(v,w)=0$ for all $w$ then we have $v=0$. Equivalently that the induced map $V\to V^*$ is injective (and hence bijective in the fin-dim case).